# Problema com trigger em select/insert

Tags: mysql, select, trigger, sql-insert

Pessoal eu criei duas entidades, onde a informação de uma é manipulada pela outra. Ou seja, possuo uma entidade `conta` e outra `conta_extrato` o saldo da entidade conta é modificado apenas com inserções na `conta_extrato`.

Consegui chegar ao resultado esperado, porém ao tentar fazer um select/insert eu me deparo com o erro abaixo:

> Can't update table 'conta' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Caso eu faça o insert de registro a registro tudo ocorre perfeitamente. Como faço para corrigir esse erro?

**SGBD =** MySQL 5.7

> DDL

```
create table conta (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  nome varchar(150),
  valor int not null default 0
);

create table conta_extrato (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  idconta int not null,
  valor int not null,
  foreign key(idconta) references conta(id)
);

-- criando trigger para controlar a conta a partir do extrato...
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trg_conta_extrato_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON conta_extrato FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE conta SET valor = valor + NEW.valor WHERE id = NEW.idconta;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

> DML

```
-- inserindo contas
insert into conta (nome) values ('josé da silva'), ('maria fernanda'), ('marcos antônio');

-- inserindo valores no extrato para teste
insert into conta_extrato (idconta, valor) values (1, 500), (2, 600), (3, 150);

-- extratos foram inseridos com sucesso
select * from conta_extrato;

-- contas foram atualizadas com sucesso
select * from conta;

-- erro acontece no select insert
insert into conta_extrato (valor, idconta)
select 500 as valor, id from conta;
```

Exemplo no DBFiddler: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c5467EmEpTzW68Uy52m8PJ/0

Comment: Do manual: `The target table of the INSERT statement may appear in the FROM clause of the SELECT part of the query, or as the table named by TABLE. However, you cannot insert into a table and select from the same table in a subquery.` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: @anonimo minha consulta não é na mesma tabela, nesse exemplo eu fiz apenas para demonstrar. Eu consulto em outra tabela.

Comment: @anonimo eu faço um inner join na tabela, agora entendi. É isso, muito obrigado.

Comment: isso não responde a pergunta mas pode dar um outro caminho, por que não usar uma *stored procudure* no lugar de uma trigger? isso iria funcionar, transacional e fica mais claro, pois todas as transações ficam no mesmo *statement*, no código da *procedure*

Comment: @RicardoPontual a stored procedure que vc fala é para fazer o trabalho do select/insert, correto?

Comment: sim, e também o update da tabela conta